# How to find the total sum of a few search terms in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, sum, kibana, aggregation, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a collection of docs as follows :

`

```
{
  "_index": "senseihub-data",
  "_type": "historical-data",
  "_id": "AVa-BvxJ9Iu6vSdmuerK",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "university": "JOHNS HOPKINS UNIVERSITY",
    "description": "FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS OF CAROTID BODY RESPONSES TO HYPOXIA IN MICE\"",
    "funding": 3327323,
    "taxonomy": "Signal Processing "
  }
}
```

`

Now I want to find the total funding info for a few taxonomies.
e.g. if I search for taxonomies : 'Signal Processing' , 'Data Mining', I want to get the following output

Signal Processing : Total sum of 'funding' field for all docs having taxonomy as Signal Processing

Data Mining : Total sum of 'funding' field for all docs having taxonomy as Data Mining

This is what I have come up with so far, but that doesn't work properly :

`

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "term":{
                  "taxonomy":"Signal Processing"
               }
            },
            {
               "term":{
                  "taxonomy":"Data Mining"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":[
      {
         "funding":{
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "aggs":{
      "funds":{
         "sum":{
            "field":"funding"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

`

I am an absolute newbie to elastic search. Please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get sum of funding for each taxonomy by

1. Use term aggregation over taxonomy to get all the taxonomies
2. Use sum aggregation as sub-aggregation over buckets from Step 1.

> ```
> {
>   "query": {
>     "match_all": {}
>   },"aggs": {
>     "taxonomy": {
>       "terms": {
>         "field": "taxonomy",
>         "size": 0
>       },"aggs": {
>           "NAME": {
>              "sum": {
>              "field": "funding"
>              }
>            }
>       }
>     }
>   },"size": 0
> }
> ```

The above query will give you sum of funding for each taxonomy .

---

If you want sum of funding for a specific taxonomy

1. Get all documents for that taxonomy using term query

   2. Use sum aggregation for results from step 1

> ```
>  {  
>    "query":{  
>       "term":{  
>          "taxonomy":{  
>             "value":"Signal Processing"
>          }
>       }
>    },
>    "aggs":{  
>       "NAME":{  
>          "sum":{  
>             "field":"funding"
>          }
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```

Make sure that the field "taxonomy" is **not analyzed** else values like "Signal Processing" will be tokenized as "Signal","Processing".

What your query is trying to achieve is:

1. Get documents with taxonomy as either "Signal Processing" or "Data Mining".
2. Sum funding for all documents from Step 1

[Bool Query Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)